# Shapely's unary_union very slow!

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am trying to execute [`unary_union`](https://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html#GeoSeries.unary_union) on a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) to run [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s [`nearest_points()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.nearest_points) method. It is taking a very long time! The set is around 6,500 points. Is there a better way to find nearest neighbor?

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Why do you need `unary_union` to be able to use `nearest_points`? Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: This is standard practice for connecting (say) points to roads.  Sometimes it works well, and sometimes it takes prohibitively long.  I don't know what makes the difference, but I want to  because I'm having this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

One work-around that I've used is:

1. create an STR tree of the things (lines or points or polygons) you want to "connect" to
2. for each point, buffer it by some amount (appropriate for your problem space)
3. get the lines that intersect that buffer using the STRtree; i.e., get all nearby lines
4. do the unary union on just those nearby lines
5. use nearest_points() on the pre-buffered point and nearby line collection

The STRtree is not essential, you can find the lines that intersect the buffer directly, but the tree search significantly speeds up the process of finding those nearby lines.

Although this works in reasonable time and solves the problem, it may be better to figure out how to get the unary union to work better/faster.  Unfortunately I myself am still looking for that information.